# Coppersmith-Tetali-Winkler Identity for Hitting Times in a Reversible Markov Chain

Tags: probability-distributions, markov-chains

I'm trying to prove the Coppersmith-Tetali-Winkler identity for hitting times ina  reversible Markov chain, that is that for any three states $a$, $b$ and $c$ in a reversible chain
$$ E_a(\tau_b) + E_b(\tau_c) + E_c(\tau_a) = E_a(\tau_c) + E_c(\tau_b) + E_b(\tau_a), \tag{$*$} $$
where $\tau_b = \inf\{n\ge0 \mid X_n=b\}$ is the hitting time of $b$.

Since this is a named identity, I thought I'd be able to find help via Google, but I haven't been able to. I have a hint which says "think of a chain starting at its stationary distribution and then going to $a$, and add this quantity to both sides of $(*)$. Try as I might, I can't get anywhere with this.

If someone could give me a slightly stronger hint, then that'd be most appreciated!

Comment: For a source, see the paper "Collisions among random walks on a graph, D. Coppersmith, P. Tetali and P. Winkler, SIAM J. Disc. Math. 6:3 (1993), pp. 363-374", numbered 63 on [Winkler's website](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~pw/papers/pubs.html).

Comment: I'd looked at that but hadn't been able to work it out from that. I'm looking for a fairly short proof -- easy enough to be left as an exercise in a paper/lecture notes. However, on looking at it again, I've found the right part, which I must have just missed before! Thanks very much! :)

Comment: So in that paper they only cover the simple random walk, whereas I'm looking at generally reversible chains. I was able to apply the same principle to obtain the answer, so thank you. :)

Comment: Indeed, if one can solve the case of simple random walks, allowing multiple edges between two vertices, then the general reversible case follows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Did's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1947760/coppersmith-tetali-winkler-identity-for-hitting-times-in-a-reversible-markov-cha#comment3998723_1947760) for the answer. I am merely posting this as an answer so that I can accept it and remove this question from the unanswered and/or unaccepted pile. (Answer written by OP)

*Do not +1 this answer -- But definitely do +1 Did's comment!*